# Where should fingers be on the home row when learning to type with the 2-set Korean keyboard (Dubeolsik 두벌식)?

Tags: typing

I want to start practicing typing Korean. I want to get into good habits from the start. I've tried to research a bit online, but it's hard to find a definitive recommendation.

In which home row position should the 8 fingers rest?

- ㅁㄴㅇㄹ ㅓㅏㅣ;
- ㅁㄴㅇㄹ ㅗㅓㅏㅣ
- somewhere else?

Having the right pinky finger on ; is the position taught for typing in English. But, looking at the Korean layout, it seems a bit wasteful to relegate the pinky mainly to ㅔ ; / when it could be used for ㅐㅔㅣ if you move your right hand one key to the left.

Which position is standard or common among typists who are fluent in Korean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's same as English QWERTY keyboard. The base position rest index finger on ㄹ and ㅓ.

Comment: 감사합니다 Thank you.